# Jupyter Notebook Display cells going up when writing new line of code

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, display

When I'm writing codes on jupyter notebook and I press enter, the cells above the current cell go up instead of the cells below the current cell going down.

Seems to be a display issue. I might have clicked on something accidentally.

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know the source of the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After I ran some codes the issue seemed to have dissapeared

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because you may have changed the cell execution order in your Jupyter Notebook.
you can find an option to 'reset the cell execution order' (two circular arrow icon) in Jupyter Notebook toolbar. it will reset the cell execution order.

If you press `enter` and the cell above the current cell is moving up, it might be because the current cell has been running.

If you want to select new cell below the current one you can manually do that by clicking on it. if you want to run the cell you can use `shift + enter` key.
There might be an issue with the kernel you can try restarting the kernel.